# rvm install 2.1.4 hangs on OSX

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

when attempting to install a new version of ruby with the command:

```
rvm install 2.1.4
```

the process hangs in the middle of compiling:

```
ruby-2.1.4 - #downloading ruby-2.1.4, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.1.4 - #extracting ruby-2.1.4 to /Users/alutz/.rvm/src/ruby-2.1.4....
ruby-2.1.4 - #configuring.....................................................
ruby-2.1.4 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.1.4 - #compiling.......\
```

Comment: If you check your ~/.rvm/log/<last>/make.log you'll see that the process hangs while _linking miniruby_. This it's a known issue, see [ruby-lang Bug #10438](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10438). Proposed fix is the same you have found on github.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solved my issue:

`rvm install 2.1.4 -- --with-setjmp-type=setjmp`

[original source of fix](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/3050#issuecomment-56666232)

[issue report on ruby-lang.org](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10438)