# rvm install 2.2.6 hangs in compiling.... no progress at all I have been waiting for long time to get it complete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm, macos-mojave

rvm install 2.2.6 is taking a lot of time to install. I have seen and tried multiple things like
this : [enter link description here][1]

[1]: other stackoverflow solution [rvm install 2.1.4 hangs on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744971/rvm-install-2-1-4-hangs-on-osx)

But still no progress. And I am using macOS Mojave(10.14) Can anyone suggest things for this issue where the issue is happening??

Checking requirements for osx.
Updating certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem'
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/syamp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.6, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.2.6 - #downloading ruby-2.2.6, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12.7M  100 12.7M    0     0  1581k      0  0:00:08  0:00:08 --:--:-- 2163k
ruby-2.2.6 - #extracting ruby-2.2.6 to /Users/syamp/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.6.....
ruby-2.2.6 - #applying patch /Users/syamp/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.2.6/fix_installing_bundled_gems.patch.
ruby-2.2.6 - #configuring..........................................................
ruby-2.2.6 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.2.6 - #compiling..........\

Comment: You don't mention how long you're waiting. In my experience ruby is pretty big and will take a good bit of time to compile. It even warns "this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)"

Are you certain it's not just busy compiling?

Comment: It's been more than 4hrs it's still compiling I have installed the same version before I did not face any issue before

Comment: Do you have a virus scanner running on your machine?

Comment: no anti virus is there

Comment: after doing 'csrutil disable' it worked for me in OSx 10.14 Mojave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after doing 'csrutil disable' it worked for me in OSx 10.14 Mojave.It is completed the compelling